# Insert horizontal axis values in line chart

Tags: charts, google-spreadsheets

I want to insert the month names in the horizontal axis of a line chart.
This should be easy to do, but after for one hour I can't figure out how to do it. This is the sheet that contains the chart and data: [Link here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D0CW1bkUCWM8yoPpJph8j1awrWZAxt5norw7w8LLtFU/edit?usp=sharing)

How can I add the month names to the x-axis???

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add column A to the chart as labels for the horizontal axis.

1. Right-click near the bottom of the chart and select `Advanced edit...`

[image: select Advanced edit...]

2. Select the `Chart types` tab.
3. Replace `Folha1!C1:C13` with `Folha1!A1:A13,Folha1!C1:C13`. Select `Use Column A as labels`.

Change this:

> [image: select chart range]

To this:

> [image: change chart range]

4. Click <kbd>Update</kbd>.

Here's the chart with month names in the horizontal axis.

[image: chart with labels]

Comment: Great, now I can see the labels but January is missing.

Comment: @NunoNogueira The date for January is `2016/01/16`. Change that to `2016/01/01` and the axis will show January. Alternatively, at Step 3, select `Aggregate column A` for slightly different axis labels.

Comment: @NunoNogueira If the precise dates on the chart are important, change the chart to a `Scatter chart`.